# Cross-compile C++ with curl for ARM

Tags: c++, ubuntu, curl, arm, libcurl

I've got a short C++ program to download a file with curl.
I can compile it with:

**gcc main.cpp -L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl -lcurl**

but when I try it to compile for my arm-development board with the command:

**arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc main.cpp -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl -lcurl**

I got an error, that lcurl cannot be found.

Can somebody tell me how to compile my program the right way or how to install curl for arm on my Linux-Ubuntu-Machine

```cpp
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
    }

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "...url...";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "/home/test.txt";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        // always cleanup
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
     }
     return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: You need to cross-compile and cross-install (not sure how) libcurl as well. BTW: The right executable for C++ is `g++` and please never compile without warnings enabled, lots of questions here could have been avoided or at least improved by warnings. Further, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and don't paraphrase but quote errors.

Comment: You do know that the `x86_64` part of e.g. `-L/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/curl` is for the 64-bit Intel x86 platform, not ARM? I think you need to spend a little more time reading about cross-platform building.

Comment: That sounds like a linker warning, @DanielStenberg, in which case the `-dev` package is already installed. It may be that the according ARM package can be installed for cross-compiling though.

Comment: You could use a package manager like Conan and a build system like CMake to manage your dependencies. Conan will download and install the dependencies for the target system. Conan and CMake support cross compilation. Triple C (C++, CMake, Conan) is a good combination.